# how to measure the total execution time with threads Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I want to measure the total execution time of my application. In particular, my application runs two threads. I want to measure the time starting from the beginning of the main until the two threads have finished their execution (basically, the total execution time of main). The problem of my code is that it seems like the total execution time is calculated before the two threads finished their execution. To check this, I put at the end of the run method of MyFirstThread class the System.out.println("end first") and I also put System.out.println("end second") at the end of the run method of MySecondThread class. The problem is that it prints out the total execution time and after that it prints out "end first" and "end second". What I want is to first print "end first" "end second" (or vice versa) and finally the total execution time.
Here my code:

```
    public static void main(String [] args) throws InterruptedException{

    long startTime = System.nanoTime(); 

    MyFirstThread first = new MyFirstThread();
    MySecondThread second = new MySecondThread(outputPath);

    new Thread(first).start();
    first.semaphore.acquire();
    new Thread(second).start();

    long totalTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
    System.out.println("Total time: " + totalTime);     

}
```

Comment: Keep references to the threads and join them before you note the total time.

Comment: That's the point of threads - they run in *parallel*, independently of each other. So after you start them, you get to the next line while the thread is still running. You can use `join` as @DavidSchwartz wrote, but you should understand what it does.

Answer (score 0):

You need to join both the Threads before calculating the total time.

```
Thread tf = new Thread(first).start();
Thread ts = new Thread(second).start();

tf.join();
ts.join();

long totalTime = System.nanoTime() - startTime;
```